# Read config file in returns null

Tags: java, filereader

In my program I need to read in a config file. Unfortunately every attempt to read it ends without getting the data correctly. Debugging showed that the inputReader always is null. The config file is in my resources folder. Can’t it be found like that or why is the inputReader only null?

```
private String result;
private final Properties property = new Properties();

public String getString(ConfigType type) {

    InputStream inputReader = null;
    try {
        inputReader = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/config");

        if (inputReader != null) {

            property.load(inputReader);
            inputReader.close();
            result = property.getProperty(type.getValue());
        }

    } catch (IOException exception){

    }
}
```

Comment: a) `catch (IOException exception){

    }` - don't silently swallow exceptions b) try `inputReader = getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");`

Comment: Your code will not compile success,you have not set the return value

Comment: Where is the `resources` folder located?

Comment: @KevinAnderson it‘s in the src/main folder

Comment: @ScaryWombat unfortunately still doesn’t work for me

Comment: are you compiling to a jar or something?

Comment: No, is it necessary to run it as a jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the reason behind `null` is invalid directory path.

don't use `/` in the directory `"**/**resources/yourfile"` if you don't have any root or parent directory of resource folder.

You don't need to assign `null` in your `inputStream`.

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/config.properties");
```

Should work.

Comment: For sone reason it doesn’t work, I tried these kind of variations already and none of them really worked